# System.IO FileNotFound exception while loading XML file

Tags: c#, xml, blazor-webassembly, filenotfoundexception

FileA and FileB are in the same folder. FileB is an XML file.

Loading`FileB` from FileA as below. I get `System.IO FileNotFound` exception.

FileA.cs:

```
public class FileA 
{     
    private XmlDocument Doc;

    public FileA()
    {             
         var filePath= "FileB.xml"; 
         Doc = new XmlDocument();
         Doc.Load(filePath); // Exception in this line - FileNotFound
    }
}
```

Project Structure in VS:

```
-Solution'Items'
   -Server
       - bin
           - debug 
               - net7.0 -> this folder has exe file.
                   - MyFiles -> FileB.xml file is copied in this folder
   -Client
       -wwwroot
       -MyFiles
            -FileA
            -FileB
   -Shared
```

May I know where I am going wrong.

Current updated filepath:

```
var filepath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../../../MyFiles",
"FileB.xml");
```

Comment: Try to provide file full path even if they are in same level.
 var filePath= Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "FileB.xml");

Comment: Why not fire up a debugger or a log statement to see the actual value of `BaseDirectory`?

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns "/".  And FilePath returns '/../MyFiles/FileB.xml' when debugged

Answer (score 2):

A class file (FileA.cs) doesn't live in a directory (barring App_Code but don't even think about that), it gets compiled into an assembly which resides in your bin directory. Pass the appropriate relative path accordingly.

So something like:

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
"../MyFiles",
"FileB.xml");
```

Also make sure the XML file actually gets copied to the output directory.

Comment: '/../MyFiles/FileB.xml'  -> This is what filePath holds when executed. Now, I get DirectoryNotFoundException. I have changed properties of xml file,
'Copy to Output Directory' to Copy always and 'Build Action' to Content. Still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Then remove the `..`? We don't know what your paths look like. Just look at the published output in your file explorer.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. My exe file is on server project. Pls see the updated folder structure with exe file. So, var filepath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../../../MyFiles",
"FileB.xml"); Is my understanding and filepath correct? Because I still get DirectoryNotFoundException.

Comment: If your `FileA` file lives in the server project, then why did you draw it under MyFiles in the _Client_ project? It's not clear to me which file resides where.

Comment: FileA(which calls fileB) and FileB(xml file) both resides under client\myfiles. But my executable is created under server project.

Comment: Xml file gets copied to output directory -> server/bin/debug/net7.0/MyFiles/FileB.xml (hope this is clear). Would appreciate if you could point where I am going wrong or if any questions.

Comment: A quick question, Hope filepath should only point to our xml file in the project, not the xml file that is copied to output directory.  Thank you.

Comment: You say in a comment under your question that `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is `/`. Are you hosting on Linux?

Comment: Rite now app only runs on localhost and on windows

Comment: For Blazor Client, I had to fetch the file using 'httpClient.GetAsync("FileB.xml")' and the file should have been placed under 'wwwroot'. Then loaded the xml using             'doc.LoadXml(FileBContent)'. Thank you all for the answer.